# SupportMapFragment in TabHost, Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my current application I am trying to add tab features. In one of tab i want to show list and in another tab i want to show map. In my previous version of app i am showing map with SupportMapFragment. So i still want to use that(Don't want to change too much code). But when i am trying to add mapfragment its showing error. Can anyone tell me how i can achieve this?

Here is my XML:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_views"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_normal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/str_rb_normal"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_satellite"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/str_rb_satellite" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb_terrain"
                    android:layout_width="161dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/str_rb_terrain" />

            </RadioGroup>
            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/rg_views"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="User Does not have Our App. Tell him/her to Download our app."
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:background="#60ffffff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rg_views"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>




        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <!-- Editext for Search -->
        <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search Contacts.."
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lst_contacts"

            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

And here is my some java code to implement tabs.

```
  TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
  tabHost.setup();
  tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
  SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  listViewPhoneBook=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);
            // add views to tab host
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("list").setIndicator("List").setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
                    return listViewPhoneBook;
                }
            }));
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("map").setIndicator("Map").setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
                    return listViewPhoneBook;  //if i use mapFragment here its showing error.
                }
```

Error:-

```
 Incompaitable type:
 required: android.view.View
 Found:  com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: Question Updated. please check error in question.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace, it gives much more information than a message

Comment: No when i write 'return mapFragment;' Then it will show syntax error not compilation or run-time error.

Comment: Ah ok, then show the signature of this method.

Comment: Anyway this error is saying to you that you have to return a View, and you are returning a fragment (which is not a view).

Comment: Ya, But i want to return map fragment. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82739/discussion-between-feantury-and-neo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change two things:

- The way to create the tabs you need is:

  `TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("map"); 
  spec.setContent(R.id.map); 
  spec.setIndicator("Map"); 
  tabs.addTab(spec);`
- Change the `RelativeLayout` of the content for a `LinearLayout`.